# Extremely Weird Thing with UILabel which displays abnormally

Tags: iphone, ios

It's hard for me to describe the problem, and I'll use screenshots. They are all from my simulator, when I test in my `iPodTouch4`, its the same.
I have several `UILabel` s, which are rects in the picture.

[image: 1.Retina display, UILabels]

Notice there are black lines on the right of some rects, which is unexpected, because I didn't code any extra behavior except for backgoundColor and frame.

When I change `UILabel` to `UIView` (nothing else changed), every thing becomes normal!
[image: Retina display, UIViews]

And when use `UILabel` not in retina display, we can see clearly than some rects have different width, but according to my code and the log, they have same width! Realllllly Weird!
[image: no retina display UILabel]

I can't figure out why. It might be something special about `UILabel`, but I can't find anywhere int the documentation.

[this is how I create labels]

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *day in [self getDaysOfTheWeek]) {
    UILabel *dayOfWeekLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [labels addObject:dayOfWeekLabel];
} 
self.dayOfWeekLabels = labels;
```

[this is where I set their frames]

```
int count = 0;
for (UILabel *dayLabel in self.dayOfWeekLabels) {
    dayLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CELL_BORDER_WIDTH + count*(self.cellWidth+CELL_BORDER_WIDTH), CELL_BORDER_WIDTH, self.cellWidth, self.daysHeader.frame.size.height);
    dayLabel.backgroundColor = self.dateBackgroundColor;
    count++;
}
```

Just as I mentioned above, simply change these UILabel to UIView in these code make them looks differently.

Comment: Please include how you are creating these labels/ views, including the exact position and size.

Answer (score 6):

Can you do a

```
dayLabel.autoresizingMask = 0;
dayLabel.frame = [...];
NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(dayLabel.frame));
```

?

Check that you have **only integer non-fractional dimensions** (42.000 or 1337.000, not 42.500 or 1337.1234). This can be the source of your display problem.

Comment: Its frame is like this {{40.8571, 1}, {38.8571, 22}},  but it convert them into integer, their positions are still not right.   And if I change UILabel to UIView, although nothing changed in frame, they displays differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating through xib then uncheck shadow enabled box, see whether it helps you out.